# Finding the solutions to $z^4 =-16$ in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am currently reading for my first course in Abstract Algebra and came across the following example: $z^4 =-16$ in $\mathbb{C}$. However, I am stuck on how the author found that 4$\theta$ is $\pi+n(2\pi)$. I have included the following statement here: 
[image]

Comment: You have $\cos(4 \theta) = -1 \implies 4 \theta = \arccos(-1) = \pi$ which yields the first term. Then, considering the complex number is rotating around a circle (of radius $2$), and the circle is periodic with period $2 \pi$, every time you rotate a distance of $2 \pi$ you return to the point you started at. You can do this $n$ times, where $n$ is an integer, which gives the $2n\pi$ term.

Comment: Just remember that $-1=\mathrm e^{i\pi}$. (much simpler to use the complex exponential).

Comment: @Mattos gotcha! So will the second term always be $2n\pi$?

Comment: It holds _for all_ $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. You can rotate by $2 \pi$, $4 \pi$, $- 100 \pi$ etc, it doesn't matter. You just start at a point and rotate around the circle $n$ times in one direction or the other and you return back to where you started.

Comment: Which book are you using?

Comment: @Shaun A First Course in Abstract Algebra by John B. Fraleigh, 7th edition! Great book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is the following:

> If $\cos \varphi=-1$ **and** $\sin\varphi =0$, then one has
>   $$
> \varphi =(2n+1)\pi,\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}.
> $$

One can check this fact by looking at the graphs of the functions $f(x)=\cos x$ and $=\sin x$.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! What if it was that $\cos(8 \theta) = 1$ and $\sin(8 \theta) = 0$ would $\theta = 2n\pi$ ?

Comment: You are welcome. In that case, you want to find out when $\cos\varphi=1$ *and* $\sin\varphi=0$, what are the possible values of $\varphi$, which should be clear from the graphs above. Then you set $\varphi=8\theta$ to get $\theta=\varphi/8=\cdots$

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to approach it. Notice that

\begin{align*}
z^{4} = -16 \Longleftrightarrow z^{4} + 16 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (z^{2} + 4i)(z^{2} - 4i) = 0
\end{align*}

Thus your problem is reduced to solve $z^{2} = \pm 4i$. You may do it by setting

$$z^{2} = x^{2} - y^{2} + 2xyi = \pm 4i$$

Or you can approach it as suggested, that is to say, write $z^{4}$ in polar coordinates. More precisely, we have $z = \rho(\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta))$. Therefore, according to the De Moivre's theorem, it follows
\begin{align*}
& \rho^{4}(\cos(4\theta) + i\sin(4\theta)) = 16(\cos(\pi + 2k\pi) + i\sin(\pi + 2k\pi)) \Longleftrightarrow\\\\
& \rho = 2\,\,\wedge\,\,\theta = \frac{\pi}{4} + \frac{k\pi}{2},\,\,k\in\textbf{Z}.
\end{align*}